# Unnamed Constructors In dart

Tags: dart

I have the following code in dart:

```
class Complex {

  num real;
  num imaginary;

  Complex(this.real, this.imaginary);

  Complex.real(num real) {
    Complex(real, 0);
    print('function constructed!!!');
  }
}

void main() {
  var a = Complex.real(1);
}
```

Therefore, I would like to know here what is wrong in the constructor: `Complex.real`... I had this question after watching tensor programming tutorial on dart on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qROCdGYRjZg&list=PLJbE2Yu2zumDjfrfu8kisK9lQVcpMDDzZ&index=3) @14:40.

And why is the initializer operator used instead `Complex.real(num real) : this(real, 0);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
Complex.real(num real) {
  Complex(real, 0);
  print('function constructed!!!');
}
```

invokes the unnamed constructor (`Complex(real, 0)`) to construct a *different* `Complex` instance and then *discards the result*.  Your `Complex.real` constructor therefore produces an uninitialized object.  You can observe this:

```dart
Complex.real(num real) {
  Complex(real, 0);
  print('${this.real}'); // Prints: null
}
```

[The syntax for making one constructor leverage another is to use `this` in an initializer list](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#redirecting-constructors):

```dart
Complex.real(num real) : this(real, 0);
```

As @lrn pointed out, redirecting constructors can't have a body, so to have the `print` line you'd need to use a factory constructor (or a static method):

```dart
factory Complex.real(num real) {
  final complex = Complex(real, 0);
  print('function constructed!!!');
  return complex;
}
```

Comment: A redirecting generative constructor (what you get with `: this(...)`) cannot have a body, so the `print` body won't work. You can use a factory constructor instead: `factory Complex.real(num real) { print(...); return Complex(real, 0); }`.